# INSERT ALL - For more than 1000 rows

Tags: java, oracle12c, mybatis

I have an *INSERT ALL* query in my program like:

```
<insert id="insertRecord" parameterType="java.util.List">
        INSERT ALL
        <foreach collection="myList" item="addrElement" index="index">
            INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3) values (#{addrElement.element1},#{addrElement.element2},#{addrElement.element3})
        </foreach>
        SELECT * FROM dual
</insert>
```

The list will hold a minimum of 10000 records.

Obviously, this is throwing an exception since *INSERT ALL* cannot handle more than 1000 records.

> ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00913: too many values

I have checked many answers in SO as well as other sites to check that, picking records more than 1000 rows is specified only for *SELECT* query and not for an *INSERT* query.

Can someone lend me a hand on this? Would be much helpful.

Comment: How about batches?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform batch insert.

```java
int batchSize = 100;
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH)) {
  YourMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(YourMapper.class);
  int size = list.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
    mapper.insertRecord(list.get(i));
    i++;
    if (i % batchSize == 0 || i == size) {
      sqlSession.flushStatements();
      sqlSession.clearCache();
    }
  }
  sqlSession.commit();
}
```

You should find an appropriate value for the `batchSize` (it depends on various factors).

The insert statement is pretty straight forward.

```xml
<insert id="insertRecord">
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
  VALUES (#{addrElement.element1}, #{addrElement.element2}, #{addrElement.element3})
</insert>
```

We have an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert).