# Performance comparison between mybaits Batch ExecutorType and for_each Xml

Tags: insert, batch-processing, mybatis, ibatis, disk-io

I have a list of records to be inserted into DB using my baits. Previously, my code is something like:

```
for(Item item :  items){
    sqlSession.insert("insert", item);
}
```

Using this method works but I find there is dynamical incremental DiskIO at `Mysql` server, due to number of items.

As I have little access to MySql configuration, and hope to resolve this high disk io issue, I find some possible solutions:

1. using `ExecutorType.BATCH` for `sqlSession`
2. insert multiple values within a single insert statement, such as: 
   `insert into Item values <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=",">  (#{item.a}, #{item.b}...) </foreach>`

Does anyone has idea which one is suitable to solve my high diskIO problem and what the main difference between these two solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to predict the effect on the disk I/O of your server, method 1 (using `ExecutorType.BATCH`) is the recommended way.
It basically inserts a certain number of items at a time.
As it internally uses JDBC's batch operation API which is designed to handle many rows, you could benefit from optimizations by the driver.

Notes:

- Finding a proper 'batch size' is important. Please see the [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142363/insert-all-for-more-than-1000-rows/55518327#55518327) in another answer.
- In case of MySQL, adding [`rewriteBatchedStatements=true`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) to the connection URL usually improves the performance significantly.

Method 2 (multi-row insert) executes a single statement binding all items at once.
It could cause memory issues.

Comment: What do you mean for  ` It could cause memory issues.`?

Comment: Assuming you insert a million items and there are ten columns in each row, the statement contains ten million placeholders (i.e. `?` in `PreparedStatement`). And the driver has to keep all parameters on memory until `execute()` is called.