# Batch Insert into mysql by springboot+mybatis, it is much slower in linux than in windows. What could have caused it?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis, druid

When I use mybatis insert 100000 records into a table in mysql, 
1. it takes about 14s when I run the application(springboot+mybatis) in windows(my pc, 16G+i7),
2. but it takes 1244s when I run the same application in centos7 (product env, 4Core+8G ECS Server).

They both connect to the same mysql server (also run on centos7). 
The network connection is better in centos7 (product env).
CPU performance is almost the same(I have tested).
The application is simple , takes only 1G memory when running.

Libraries versions in my application:
openjdk version "1.8.0_212",
Spring boot 2.1.6 ,
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar ,
spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar ,
druid-1.1.19.jar ,
mybatis-3.5.2.jar ,
mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar ,
mybatis-spring-boot-starter-2.1.0.jar ,
mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.jar ,
mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar ,

Anyone know the reason ?
Thanks in advance.

==============================

Insert By Foreach (max_allowed_packet has been set to 200M):

```
<insert id="insertBatch" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="false">
    insert into table_product
        (id,
        code,
        status,
        type,
        create_time,
        update_time)
    values
    <foreach collection="products" item="product" index="index" separator=",">
        (#{product.id},
        #{product.code},
        #{product.status},
        #{product.type},
        #{product.createTime},
        #{product.updateTime})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

==================================

Insert By ExecutorType.BATCH:

```
public void batchInsert(List<Product> products){
    SqlSession session = sqlSessionTemplate.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false);
    BatchTableDao batchTableDao = session.getMapper(BatchTableDao.class);
    try {
        int i=0;
        for (Product product : products) {
            batchTableDao.insert(product);
            if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == products.size()-1) {
                session.flushStatements();
                session.clearCache();
            }
            i++;
        }
        session.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.warn("error : "+e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

===================================

In windows 10, it takes about 14s to insert 100000 rows by using 'foreach'.
And it takes about 2500s to insert 100000 rows by using 'ExecutorType.BATCH', it is too slow to accept.

Comment: 'Why' is a difficult question for others to answer, but in general, multi-row insert is not suitable when dealing with many rows. You should consider switching to batch insert. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56040127/1261766) and the linked sample code.

Comment: But I find it is really slow by using ExecutorType.BATCH to insert a lot of row. It is about 100 times slower than the way of using 'foreach'.  I haved appended the code. Thanks.

Comment: That does not seem right. If you could share the project on GitHub or alike, I would take a look when I have some spare time. If the project is big, it may be better to create a small single-table project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: Here is my simplified code. [batch](https://github.com/cnisky/batch) . Thanks.

Comment: I've just sent a PR. Changes are (1) added `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to the JDBC URL (2) put batch statement execution in a single session.

Comment: It works, greate thanks.  But it is still very slow when running in centos, it takes 1546s for insert 1000,000 rows in centos, and it takes only 87s in window 10. Is there anything should be changed when deploy the application in centos ?

Comment: It seems that, on some EC2 instances, `System.currentTimeInMills()` (or `System.nanoTime()` ) can be slow. See this [post](https://medium.com/appian-engineering/yet-another-reason-your-docker-containers-may-be-slow-on-ec2-clock-gettime-gettimeofday-and-9d92f6892048). Could this be the reason?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried some params mentioned in that POST, it doesn't work. I believe some system clock or kernal thread works different for linux, it would be faster if using thread pool to insert every small batches?

Comment: No idea. :D It seems more like a ECS/EC2 issue rather than a Linux/CentOS issue to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how about changing to the version specified in [the official document](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/)? And I think you need to know more about the code.

Comment: I have changed the version to the official requirements, but the issue is the same. And I have also tried the Batch Insert by using ExecutorType.BATCH, it is really slow. Thanks.