# MyBatis multi-row INSERT using SQL Builder

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using MyBatis (mybatis-spring-boot-starter 2.0), I want to insert list of values into table using java [sqlBuilder](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html). I know how to write sqlBuilder in java for storing single record. But how to write the sqlBuilder for List of records?

Mapper interface (Single record):

```java
@InsertProvider(method = "insert", type = TestSqlBuilder.class)
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "id", keyProperty = "id")
public void save(final TestVO testVO );
```

TestSqlBuilder.java (Single record):

The below method used for inserting single TestVO values.

```java
public String insert() {
  return new SQL() {
    {
      INSERT_INTO("TEST")
      .VALUES("COL1", "#{col1}")
      .VALUES("COL2", "#{col2}")
      .VALUES("COL3", "#{col3}")
      .VALUES("COL3", "#{col4}")
      .toString();
    }
  }.toString();
}
```

Now for List of records, how to write sqlBuilder.

Else how can we convert the below to sqlBuilder java code

```java
@Insert("<script>                                  "
        + "insert into sys_user                    "
        + "(t_id, t_name, t_age)                   "
        + "values                                  "
        + "<foreach collection='list' item='item'  "
        + " index='index' separator=','>           "
        + "(#{item.id}, #{item.name}, #{item.age}) "
        + "</foreach>                              "
        + "</script>                               ")
int insertUserListWithForeach(List<User> list);
```

Comment: Just FYI, a [pull request](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1333) for this enhancement is under review right now.

Comment: @ave Do you mean the implementation for the above (multiple insert) is yet to be done/released

Comment: Yes, that is correct. BTW, if you need to insert a lot of rows, I recommend using [batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518327/1261766) instead for performance reasons.