# how to inject pl/pgsql in myBatis 3 xml mapper

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using MyBatis 3.3.0 with Postgresql 12. I want to inject some pl/pgsql in my xml mapper

for example: to insert data with for loop

```
 <update id="generateNumbers" parameterType="tn.tt.nbms.dto.RangeDTO" statementType="CALLABLE">


<![CDATA[ 
   declare 
     ..... 
   begin 
      for number in ...... 
             insert into.....(....) values (...) 
      end loop; 
   end; ]]> 
</update>
```

with oracle and Pl/sql it works fine
but I can't convert it to pl/pgsql
How can I do it
I know I can use stored procedure  but my question is how to inject pl/pgsql  in xml mapper files if it is possible?

Comment: Why would you want to use a PL/pgSQL loop to insert data?

Comment: we have an application that runs on oracle  and we want to migrate to posgresql  I should just convert the sql and try to not add new db objects

Comment: You don't need that in Postgres, you can use `insert into .. select ... from generate_series(...)` no loop required. In Postgres you need to use a `do` block

Comment: the problem is not with the loop even without it it doesn't work I want to know how to write callable statement in xml mapper if posgresql it is used

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Why do you think you need a callable statement to simply insert multiple rows? Did you try a [`do` block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) which is the Postgres equivalent to an anonymous PL/SQL block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that for poqgresql (unlike oracle) we can not set parameters to anonymous code block

so we can use batch operations

[1] https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518327/

or stored procedure

I hope that will help some one ....