# How to bulk insert in MariaDB?

Tags: spring, mariadb, mybatis, bulkinsert

I want to ask about bulk insert of MariaDB

While I'm searching for get information about bulk insert,
I found a solution
That is

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

But I'm using list parameter in mybatis. so I can't use this solution

```
INSERT INTO RaffleData
        (
            raffleNo,                       storeNo,                storeId,            favoriteArea,               modelId,
            size,                           personName,             personId,           createDate_join1,           createDate_join2,
            createDate_web_join,            email,                  birthDate,          isOut,                      address,
            creator,                        createDate,             isDelete,
            randomNo,                       rank2,                  fileNo
        )
```

That is

```
<foreach item="item" separator="," collection="raffleDataList">
        <![CDATA[
        (
            #{item.raffleNo},               #{item.storeNo},        #{item.storeId},    #{item.favoriteArea},       #{item.modelId},
            #{item.size},                   #{item.personName},     #{item.personId},   #{item.createDate_join1},   #{item.createDate_join2},
            #{item.createDate_web_join},    #{item.email},          #{item.birthDate},  #{item.isOut},              #{item.address},
            #{item.creator},                NOW(),                  false,
            #{item.randomNo},               #{item.rank2},          #{item.fileNo}
        )
        ]]>
```

I want to apply for extended bulk insert for optimize SQL query
But I don't know how to apply list parameters.

I'm not used to writing English Writing.
If you know about this problem, please solution to me

Comment: Which language/framework are you using for insert operation?

Comment: Java/Spring and Mybatis

Comment: You can use `<foreach />` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133307/1261766). Consider using [batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518327/1261766) if the list contains many items.

Comment: Those don't sound like numbers?  You need quotes around strings.