# Bulk Insert with Spring-boot and my mybatis

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I am writing spring-boot application with my-batis. I am using annotation to handle insert, select or update operation. I was wondering if it is possible to do bulk insert.

I tried an obvious fail

```
@Insert(A_SIMPLE_INSERT_QUERY)
Integer bulkInsert(List<Simple> inp);
```

Any help is appreciated.

--edit--
I have implemented bulk insert using `JdbcTemplate` wondering if simpler ways exists or not.

Comment: You can use [`<foreach>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17563463/1261766) if the number of items is small. If the number is large, use [batch executor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518327/1261766). This [demo](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/cockroachdemo/MyBatisConfiguration.java) shows you how to configure two sets of mappers (batch and non-batch) with mybatis-spring-boot.